# IN SQL INNER JOIN can you add two tables with different columns?

Tags: sql, inner-join

Hi im currently new to SQL. Im trying to select checkindate and checkout columns from the booking table and firstname and lastname from the customer table. The two tables share a common column which is customerID. Can anyone help me please!!

```
Booking table:
bookingID (pk)
checkindate
checkoutdate 
customerID (fk)

Customer table:
customerID (pk)
firstname 
lastname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT booking.checkindate, booking.checoutdate, customer.firstname, customer.lastname
FROM booking 
JOIN customer 
ON booking.customerID = customer.customerID
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bt.customerid,checkindate,firstname ,lastname  
FROM BookingTable bt inner join CustomerTable ct 
     on bt.customerid=ct.customerid
```

Comment: Never use joins like this. Use standard ANSI joins.

Comment: appreciate it. Please use b.checkindate instead of c.checkindate in your answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join as follows:

```
SELECT B.customerid,
       B.checkindate,
       C.firstname ,
       C.lastname 
  FROM BookingTable b
  join CustomerTable c on b.customerid=c.customerid
```

Comment: You have to write B.Checkindate instead of C.Checkindate